# GitLab in localhost, no formatting

Tags: nginx, redis, gitlab

On my local Arch Linux machine I installed GitLab from via the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GitLab).

When I try to open the website on localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8081 I get a page without formatting:

[image: gitlab change password page]

When I try to set a password I get:

```
8 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
- Email can't be blank
- Password can't be blank
- Namespace route can't be blank
- Namespace name can't be blank
- Name can't be blank
- Username can't be blank
- Username can't be blank
- Username can contain only letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.'. Cannot start with '-' or end in '.', '.git' or '.atom'.
```

[image: password error]

I followed the whole guide.

The thing that to me seemed to be missing:

1. setting some port for gitlab in nginx
2. symlinking the gitlab config file in nginx (step 2.9.1)

Why is the formatting is not working, and the password change gives errors that doesn't make sense?

It took me a long time to get the unixsocket working in redis, but from the environment variable checks I did manage in the end.

Edit from the browsers dev console I get:

```
Refused to load the font 'data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAALY3ABIAAAABztAAAAAAAAC1QAAAAPcAAAHiAAAAAAAAAABHUE9TAACV9AAAFxIAAHKy/pn970dTVUIAAK0IAAAINQAAFD6g2KReTFRTSAAABtQAAAA6AAACQeO3nq5PUy8yAAACDAAAAFMAAABgZoZye2NtYXAAABxsAAADdwAABTpa8HPyY3Z0IAAAIbAAAAAoAAAAKAhGAbdmcGdtAAAf5AAAAQUAAAFzBpmcN2dhc3AAAJXoAAAADAAAAAwABwAHZ2x5ZgAAJkQAAGT0AADhaCjCChFoZG14AAAHEAAAFVwAADPIhU9AOGhlYWQAAAGUAAAANQAAADYFph12aGhlYQAAAcwAAAAgAAAAJAc2BPtobXR4AAACYAAABHEAAAj0jIVtDGxvY2EAACHYAAAEbAAABHyCc7p8bWF4cAAAAewAAAAgAAAAIARXAjxuYW1lAACLOAA...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

password:1 Refused to load the font 'data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64, d09GRgABAAAAALM7AA8AAAABq0AAAAAAAACyRAAAAPcAAAHiAAAAAAAAAABHUE9TAACIDAAAIgQAAH82Ol56cUdTVUIAAKoQAAAIMwAAFD6gNKPBT1MvMgAAAdAAAABVAAAAYGbqc4pjbWFwAAAGbAAAA3wAAAU4Vch3gWN2dCAAAAwYAAAAQAAAAEAQPwNiZnBnbQAACegAAAEDAAABcwZZnDdnbHlmAAAQvAAAbJ4AAOZUwSn/MmhlYWQAAAFYAAAANgAAADYGApswaGhlYQAAAZAAAAAgAAAAJAdbBRtobXR4AAACKAAABEIAAAjwrN1ggGxvY2EAAAxYAAAEYgAABHqHyk9obWF4cAAAAbAAAAAgAAAAIARWA2ZuYW1lAAB9XAAAAoEAAAZuOd88j3Bvc3QAAH/gAAAIKgAAEi5ynk2NcHJlcAAACuwAAAEqAAACpAoaNTMAAQAAAAEAAA...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

password:1 Refused to load the font 'data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64, d09GRgABAAAAAMjjABIAAAAB2mAAAAAAAADH7AAAAPcAAAHiAAAAAAAAAABHUE9TAACdfAAAIjcAAH80VqR1REdTVUIAAL+0AAAINwAAFD6g7KTPTFRTSAAABwQAAABHAAACQYV/Ri1PUy8yAAACDAAAAFQAAABgZ050kmNtYXAAAB1cAAAChQAAA/wdE0d/Y3Z0IAAAIdQAAAA0AAAANAq+BC1mcGdtAAAf5AAAAQUAAAFzBpmcN2dhc3AAAJ1wAAAADAAAAAwABwAHZ2x5ZgAAJnAAAGxKAADg/GpVnLBoZG14AAAHTAAAFhAAADPIAPyiAmhlYWQAAAGUAAAANQAAADYF/aZQaGhlYQAAAcwAAAAgAAAAJAdxBTBobXR4AAACYAAABKIAAAj0wQRTzWxvY2EAACIIAAAEZwAABHxHMIAQbWF4cAAAAewAAAAgAAAAIARXAs1uYW1lAACSvA...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

password:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=f5d7HAJzHr9H9Y2FeXDe' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
password:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=ddakboEDSrmuDD7x89WM' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
password:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=EpcdmHy2ZpwoZ8dPBM5m' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
password:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=LPU1u168VBn2zgvo3x-h' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
password:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=YnvtsaFsWta_8SfBpg5U' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
password:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=NxtjP2MX13M54nZSTLfJ' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Under "issues" I have:

```
Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources
Some resources are blocked because their origin is not listed in your site's Content Security Policy (CSP). Your site's CSP is allowlist-based, so resources must be listed in the allowlist in order to be accessed.
A site's Content Security Policy is set either as via an HTTP header (recommended), or via a meta HTML tag.
To fix this issue do one of the following:
(Recommended) If you're using an allowlist for 'script-src', consider switching from an allowlist CSP to a strict CSP, because strict CSPs are more robust against XSS . See how to set a strict CSP .
Or carefully check that all of the blocked resources are trustworthy; if they are, include their sources in the CSP of your site. ⚠️Never add a source you don't trust to your site's CSP. If you don't trust the source, consider hosting resources on your own site instead.
1 directive
Resource    Status  Directive   Source Location
data    blocked font-src    edit:166
```

When I check `systemctl status nginx` I get:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-01-08 06:54:59 CST; 1h 11min ago
    Process: 408 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 432 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18846)
     Memory: 5.8M
        CPU: 15ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─432 "nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr;"
             └─433 "nginx: worker process"

Jan 08 06:54:59 Latitude7420 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jan 08 06:54:59 Latitude7420 nginx[408]: 2023/01/08 06:54:59 [warn] 408#408: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
Jan 08 06:54:59 Latitude7420 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jan 08 06:59:38 Latitude7420 nginx[433]: 2023/01/08 06:59:38 [error] 433#433: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1">
Jan 08 08:03:23 Latitude7420 nginx[433]: 2023/01/08 08:03:23 [error] 433#433: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1">
```

Comment: Can you check if there are any errors logged in your browser's dev console?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add the sample `nginx.conf` from the arch install guide of nginx (section 3.1), overriding the default conf file.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Nginx#Configuration

`nginx.conf` :

```
user http;
worker_processes auto;
worker_cpu_affinity auto;

events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;
    log_not_found off;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    client_max_body_size 16M;

    # MIME
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    # load configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```